# Modeling User to User connections in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an User object and a Connection object to manage connections between users.

```
class User:
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
```

and

```
class Connection:
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    friend = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="_friends", symmetrical=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="_followers", symmetrical=False)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="_following", symmetrical=False)
```

I'm not sure how to add friends in this modeling.

```
user.connection_set._friends.add(target) -> does this work?
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Connections are following connections? Shouldn't these connections just have two `User`s?

Comment: I want to use an intermittent object to manage UserConnections. If I haven't modeled it right, can you tell me the best way to model this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a OneToOne (i guess your User has only one Connection with multiple followers, friends etc?)

If you use a FK or m2m field you need one more step to find which Connection you will use (something like User.objects.get(XXXX).connection.get(XXXX)

```
class User:
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,)

class Connection:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    friend = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="_friends", symmetrical=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="_followers", symmetrical=False)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="_following", symmetrical=False)


user = User.objects.last()
user_to_add = User.objects.first()
user.connection.followers.add(user_to_add)
```